# Why didn't the tech staff find any faults in their system check when the chip was removed?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me-2

Here the Horsemen start the card trick to fool the guards:

[image: Card trick]

In the background you can see the tech staff conducting a systems check.

Here the trick is over, they are leaving and the staff are still conducting the check:

[image: Main characters leave]

They stole a vital component, so why haven't they found any errors in the system yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the whole sequence takes approximately **5 minutes** and a hugely complex sytem like that would take some considerable time to complete a full diagnostic which is ordered by this guy..

[image]

That said, the "chip" stolen would seem to be a highly important component so you would have thought that it would be the first thing checked.

The Horseman don't swap out the chip for another one so it is curious.

Of course, it's revealed at the end that

> The tech team leader was part of the "Eye" and so was in on the caper.[image]